# How to start Appium Local Service with Elevated privileges programatically from C#

Tags: c#, android, automated-tests, appium, appium-desktop

I'm starting the latest Appium Local server with the following C# code:

```
    var service = AppiumLocalService.BuildDefaultService();
    service.Start();
```

This worked fine for me until I needed to install an .apk file onto the device I was running with Appium as part of my test run.  The capabilities I passed to the `AndroidDriver<AndrioidElement>(uri, caps)` constructor were:

```
    ("automationName", "UiAutomator2")
    ("platformName", "android")
    ("platformVersion", "8.0")
    ("app", @"c:\test\testapp.apk")
```

at which point I discovered that the automatic signing of the .apk file failed unless the Appium server was running with elevated (Administrator) privileges.

However, when I start the Appium server programmatically through the `AppiumLocalService.BuildDefaultService()` the launched instance of the Appium node server is not running with any elevated privileges and therefore the signing fails.  How can I launch the Appium server programmatically like this but have it be elevated in privileges so that the signing works?